# InstallShield 2011 SYSINFO.bIsWow64 returns incorrect value

Tags: installshield-2011

I am working on an installer that has long worked properly. I've made some minor changes to the payloads. The actual payload that is installed depends on SYSINFO.bIsWow64. However, recently this has been return an incorrect value when running on a 64 bit version of Win 7 - it returns 0 indicating that it is running on a 32 bit OS.

Has anyone experienced similar problems? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the output says the right thing:

```
if bIsWow64 then
   messagebox ("64 bit")
else
   messagebox("32 bit")
fi
```

Sometimes a second pair of eyes is a very good thing.